# how to allow the user to manually edit a properties file in an android app?

Tags: java, android, editor, properties-file

I have an android app that uses a properties file that is currently stored on the sdcard.

I want to allow the user to manually edit this properties file.

Is there a preferred editor that people use or do you roll your own for your app?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a preferred editor that people use

I am not aware of any Android device that ships with a text editor, let alone a dedicated properties file editor. I would be fairly surprised if there are any.

The Android SDK does not ship with a properties file editor, unless you count `EditText`. I am not aware of any libraries that implement a properties file editor.

> do you roll your own for your app?

Most Android developers do not use properties files on-device. Instead, they use preferences, which come with their own UI (`PreferenceScreen` and kin) and backing store (`SharedPreferences`, plus `PreferenceDataStore` on Android O).

You would need to create your own UI for editing your properties. Or, depending upon your use case, you might implement a more traditional preference-based system, using the properties file for import/export.

Comment: my core code runs on any jvm, so i elected to just use a properties file.

Comment: @RayTayek: That is fine. Just understand that this is unusual in the Android space, and so you will be on your own more than you might otherwise expect.

Comment: yes, it seems unusual. i had code to use shared preferences in the android version, but still there was no way to manually edit it, so i tossed it.